# create new workbook from selection in excel

Tags: copy-paste

I have a monthly workbook with the detail of about 37000 lines and say 350 clients.
The clients must get their detail in a separate workbook which I will attach with their Pastel invoice.

I want a macro to:

1. After selecting a clients range.
2. Open a new workbook and paste the selection in `A1`
3. Then save the workbook in a seperate directory (example: `C:\Aug2013Detail`)
4. Save the workbook with the name of the client in `A2` of the new book (client name always in `A2` after pasting)

Thus ending up with 350 seperate workbooks in that directory

Thank you very much. 
Hennie Koch

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around a bit and this works perfect!!!!!
Hennie

```vb
Sub Macro13()
  '
  ' Macro13 Macro
  '
  ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
  '
  Selection.Copy
  Workbooks.Add
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ThisFile = Range("A2").Value
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile
  ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```